# Join con LinQ de varias condiciones

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Tengo esta query en SQL:

```
SELECT 
    encf.numero, 
    encf.fecha, 
    cuef.cod_mer, 
    cuef.descrip, 
    cuef.cantidad, 
    cuef.im_pe_un 
FROM encf
JOIN cuef
    ON encf.numero = cuef.numero 
    AND encf.[manual] = cuef.[manual]
    AND encf.comproba = cuef.comproba
    AND encf.tipo_fac = cuef.tipo_fac
    AND encf.sucursal = cuef.sucursal
WHERE 
    encf.documento = 123456
```

Estaba intentando hacer algo como esto:

```
var query = from enc in db.encf
                        join cue in db.cuef
                            on new { enc.numero, enc.manual, enc.comproba, enc.tipo_fac, enc.sucursal } 
                            equals new { cue.numero, cue.manual, cue.comproba, cue.tipo_fac, cue.sucursal }                               
                        select new encfcuef
                        {
                            numero = enc.numero,
                            fecha = Convert.ToDateTime(enc.fecha),
                            descrip = cue.descrip,
                            cantidad = cue.cantidad ?? 0,
                            cod_mer = cue.cod_mer,
                            im_pe_un = cue.im_pe_un ?? 0
                        };
```

Pero tengo error en la instruccion **join** y no se por que. Alguno me sugiere como solucionarlo?

Y tambien, como se podria hacer con Lambda?
Gracias! Saludos!

Comment: Nos decis que tenes un error, y te creemos. Pero es mejor que nos muestres que error te da (como texto) y cual es la linea o el contexto donde te da el mismo.

Comment: Si, tenes razon! Ahi va. Justo sobre la palabra **join** me da un ArgumentNullException y dice "The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect. Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'". Y no entiendo por que si todo lo que estoy comparando son del mismo tipo de dato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podria ser que tu fecha no este en formato correcto o null, otra cosa podria ser que alguno de los campos sea null, la la segunda opcion Lambda seria como se muestra en ejemplo siguiente.

Ejemplo:

```
 var query = db.encf.Join(db.cuef,
                    enc => new { enc.numero, enc.manual, enc.comproba, enc.tipo_fac, enc.sucursa },
                    cue => new { cue.numero, cue.manual, cue.comproba, cue.tipo_fac, cue.sucursal },
                    (enc, cue) => new { enc, cue }
                    )
                    .Select(r => new encfcuef
                    {
                        numero = r.enc.numero,
                        fecha = Convert.ToDateTime(r.enc.fecha),
                        descrip = r.cue.descrip,
                        cantidad = r.cue.cantidad ?? 0,
                        cod_mer = r.cue.cod_mer,
                        im_pe_un = r.cue.im_pe_un ?? 0
                    });// .Where();
```

Comment: Gracias, encontre el problema por tu respuesta. La propiedad manual, en una permite null y otra no! Era eso. Y gracias por la forma en lambda, creo que prefiero linq que queda mas prolijo con multiples condiciones. Saludos!

Comment: prueba agregandolo antes del select